# 0-1 knapsack dynamic programming solution does not work

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, knapsack-problem

This is the 0-1 knapsack problem dynamic programming code found on geeks for geeks. I've changed the input for my own test, but it doesn't seem to work. Wouldn't the optimal solution be 1 of item 4 (v:10, w:7) and 3 of item 1 (v:1, w:1) adding up to 13? When I run the code and do the algorithm by hand it turns out to be 12 with items 2 and 4. Where am I going wrong?

```
// A Dynamic Programming based solution for 0-1 Knapsack problem
#include<stdio.h>

// A utility function that returns maximum of two integers
int max(int a, int b) { return (a > b)? a : b; }

// Returns the maximum value that can be put in a knapsack of capacity W
int knapSack(int W, int wt[], int val[], int n)
{
int i, w;
int K[n+1][W+1];

// Build table K[][] in bottom up manner
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    for (w = 0; w <= W; w++)
    {
        if (i==0 || w==0)
            K[i][w] = 0;
        else if (wt[i-1] <= w)
            K[i][w] = max(val[i-1] + K[i-1][w-wt[i-1]], K[i-1][w]);
        else
            K[i][w] = K[i-1][w];
    }
}

return K[n][W];
}

int main()
{
    int val[] = {1, 2, 5, 10};
    int wt[] = {1, 3, 4, 7};
    int W = 10;
    int n = sizeof(val)/sizeof(val[0]);
    printf("%d", knapSack(W, wt, val, n));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because this algorithm solves **0-1** Knapsack problem.

In this formulation only one instance of every item is available. That is why solution uses items once.

*(perhaps you was thinking about knapsack with unlimited (or restricted) quantity for every item)*

Comment: Thanks haha, I knew I was going to feel stupid after I got the answer.